# Convert C++ non-capturing lambda to void*

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a little class for callback with parameter

```
template<typename Ret, typename ...Args>
class Callback
{
public:
    typedef Ret (*Ptr)(Args..., void* param);
    Ptr m_func;
    void* m_param;
    void setFunc(void* func) { m_func = (Ptr)func; }
    template<typename T>
    void setFunc(const T& func) { m_func = (Ptr)func; }
};
```

"param" member is a void pointer, but it actually may point to different structs even in context of one callback
So I can use setFunc with simple function like this:

```
void func1(..., ExampleContext* param) { ... }
callback.setFunc(func1);
```

But with non-capturing lambda I can only use it with strict void type:

```
callback.setFunc([](..., void* param) { ... });
```

I can convert lambda to its pointer, but I should write its typedef and cast, while I want setFunc to accept lambdas with any param type without additional conversions outside of Callback class, can I do it somehow? Thank you.

Comment: Why isn't `func` and `param` both `std::function<Ret(Args...)>`? The user can pass custom callback data with `std::bind`.

Comment: I can't use std::function, because it's too heavy...

Comment: This is all UB. You can cast a function pointer, but you must cast it back before calling. In your class, you lose the original type, so you have nothing to cast back to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like this should work:

```cpp
template<typename Ret, typename Param = void, typename ...Args>
class Callback
{
public:
    template<typename T = Param>
    using Ptr = Ret (*)(Args..., T *param);
    Ptr<> m_func;
    Param *m_param;
    template<typename T = Param>
    void setFunc(Ptr<T> func) { m_func = (Ptr<>)func; }
};
```

Working copy:https://ideone.com/amapu0

However, you should be aware that using m_func without casting it back to the correct type is UB. While it is possible to do what you asked, this type of casting and dependence on UB is generally a sign that your code needs to be refactored. This is probably an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). To get a more appropriate solution, you'll have to explain WHY you want the m_param in a single instance of Callback to point to different types.

Comment: As I said before, parameter may have different type even in one callback...

Comment: Updated to fix issue

Comment: This is UB because you are calling a function with a pointer that has been cast to a different type. You need to have an adapter that casts back. `void (*m_invoker)(Ptr<>func, Args..., void* param);` and create the invoker with something like `m_invoker = [](Ptr<> func, Args... args, void* param) { ((Ptr<T>)func)(args..., (T*)param); }`;` Basically, what we've done is create a very specialized version of `std::function`.

Comment: @RaymondChen I was assuming he had some way of performing the cast back at the point where the function was used. However, you're correct that it is UB, and I will update my answer with the extra information when I get the chance.

Comment: Since the example passes a lambda expression, the caller has no way to cast back because the type is lost.